# Slide Div Across Page using JQuery/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-animate, slide

I have used the following code which makes it every time you click on the div it will animate and move across the page, thus moving the next one across after it.

http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/ykbgT/2/

However, I am trying to make it so it automatically scrolls every 3 seconds without having to click. I have tried the following adjustments to the javascript using a timer but it seems to just spazz out and not scroll correctly:

```
<script>

    $('.box').click(function () {

        $(this).animate({
            left: '-50%'
        }, 500, function () {
            $(this).css('left', '150%');
            $(this).appendTo('#container');
        });

        $(this).next().animate({
            left: '50%'
        }, 500);
    });

    $(document).ready(function ()
    {

        setInterval(function ()
        {

            $('.box').click();
            console.log("BOX CLICKED.");

        }, 3000);

    });


</script>
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to Zack's answer(but simpler, IMHO), I've found that the following works for you

```
id = 1

setInterval(function(){
    $('#box' + id).animate({
        left: '-50%'
    }, 500, function() {
        $(this).css('left', '150%');
        $(this).appendTo('#container');
    });

    $('#box' + id).next().animate({
        left: '50%'
    }, 500);

    id = id <= 5 ? id + 1 : 1;
},4000)
```

Comment: Much better way. Im silly when it comes to small adjustments like this.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it by using the following adjustments:

```
<script>

    ActiveDashboards = {};
    ActiveDashboards["Projects"] = true;
    ActiveDashboards["SHEQs"] = false;
    ActiveDashboards["HR"] = false;

    function ShowNextDashboard()
    {

        if (ActiveDashboards["Projects"] == true)
        {
            //Hide this one.
            $('#box1').animate({
                left: '-50%'
            }, 500, function () {
                $('#box1').css('left', '150%');
                $('#box1').appendTo('#container');
            });


            //Show SHEQs one.
            $('#box2').animate({
                left: '50%'
            }, 500);

            ActiveDashboards["Projects"] = false;
            ActiveDashboards["SHEQs"] = true;

        }
        else if (ActiveDashboards["SHEQs"] == true)
        {

            //Hide this one.
            $('#box2').animate({
                left: '-50%'
            }, 500, function () {
                $('#box2').css('left', '150%');
                $('#box2').appendTo('#container');
            });


            //Show HR one.
            $('#box3').animate({
                left: '50%'
            }, 500);

            ActiveDashboards["SHEQs"] = false;
            ActiveDashboards["HR"] = true;

        }
        else if (ActiveDashboards["HR"] == true)
        {

            //Hide this one.
            $('#box3').animate({
                left: '-50%'
            }, 500, function () {
                $('#box3').css('left', '150%');
                $('#box3').appendTo('#container');
            });


            //Show Projects one.
            $('#box1').animate({
                left: '50%'
            }, 500);

            ActiveDashboards["HR"] = false;
            ActiveDashboards["Projects"] = true;
        }  

    }


    $(document).ready(function ()
    {

        setInterval(function ()
        {

            ShowNextDashboard();

        }, 4000);

    });


</script>
```

Probably a better way of doing it, but it's working fine and scrolling through each one.